# LambertW function in python 3.5 gives NAN for branch -1 for arg < -1E-162

Tags: python, numpy

I have been working with a problem involving LambertW functions for the branch -1, valid from lambertw(-1/e,-1)=-1 to lambertw(-0,-1) = -inf. The argument is "ridiculously" small: I want an answer for lambertw(-1,-2E-278). Using Mathematica or WolframAlpha this gives a sensible answer. However, when I tried it using Python (Anaconda Python 3.5, in Spyder 3.0) it gives a NAN. I tried different arguments for lambertw(x,-1) and the limit for answers != NAN seems to be -1E-162. My guess is that the numerical library used has limitations here. Can anyone confirm this?

Short on the background behind the "ridiculous" argument: I tried to calculate the atmospheric von Karman limit, which involves solving the following equation:

(R+x)*exp(-x/H) = y for x, where y ~ 3000-7000 and H ~ 11000, R = 6371000 The answer is

h = -H*lambertw(-exp(R/H)*y/H,-1) - R.

Thank you,

Sören

Comment: Without knowing exactly what's on topic there, this _might_ be better suited for [scicomp.se]. Make sure to [check what's on topic there](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first, though.

Answer (score 0):

The [mpmath](http://mpmath.org) library easily handles that argument for `LambertW`.

```
from mpmath import mp

x = mp.mpf('-2E-278')
y = mp.lambertw(x, k=-1)
print(x, y, y * mp.exp(y))
```

**output**

```
-2.0e-278 -645.896147400105 -1.99999999999992e-278
```

If you want more precision, just set `mp.dps`. Eg, for `mp.dps = 50` we get

```
-2.0e-278 -645.89614740010513774585665162486252955835623920946 -1.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999998e-278
```

`mpmath` is available for Python 3 and Python 2, and can easily be installed on Linux systems using `pip`. But please see the `mpmath` link above for more detailed installation information.